# Victory chart give range of 10 in y axis

Tags: reactjs, react-native, victory-charts, victory-native

I creating bar chart. I want to give range to y axis for e.g currently y axis showing  5, 10,15,20 but I want 10,20,30 a range of 10. How can I achieve that?

[image]

```
   <VictoryAxis
        domain={{y: [0, 30]}}
        dependentAxis
        orientation="left"
        style={{
          tickLabels: {fontSize: 12},
          axis: {stroke: 'transparent'},
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to change the default axis of your chart you need to provide one or more `<VictoryAxis />` components as children.

To change the interval of the ticks just set the `tickCount` prop on each axis where `tickCount` equals the division of your full domain range by the desired interval range e.g.

`30 / 10 = 3` for the y-axis

and

`20 / 10 = 2` for the x-axis because the domain range here is actual 20, not 40.

```
<VictoryChart
  domain={{ x: [ 20, 40 ], y: [ 0, 30 ]}}
>
  <VictoryAxis
    tickCount={ 3 }
    dependentAxis={ true } /* To target the y-axis */
  />
  <VictoryAxis
    tickCount={ 2 }
  />
  <VictoryScatter
    data={ [
      { x: 25, y: 10, label: 'Foo' },
      { x: 32, y: 28, label: 'Bar' }
    ] }
    size={ 3 }
  />
</VictoryChart>
```

[image]